# Stunnel Error - Cannot open Log File

Tags: centos, chroot, ssl, stunnel

Using the following stunnel config file:

```
chroot = /var/run/stunnel
setuid = nobody
setgid = nobody

debug = 7 
output = /var/log/stunnel/stunnel.log 
pid = /stunnel.pid

cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem 
key = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem 
client = yes

[https] 
accept = 127.0.0.1:10051
connect = 10.0.10.116:443
```

Typing 'sudo stunnel' I get the following output. (The config file works if I use the foreground command and send the log to the terminal)

```
[chuck@scorch ~]$ sudo stunnel
Clients allowed=500
stunnel 4.56 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu platform
Compiled/running with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
Threading:PTHREAD Sockets:POLL,IPv6 SSL:ENGINE,OCSP,FIPS Auth:LIBWRAP
Reading configuration from file /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
FIPS mode is enabled
Compression not enabled
PRNG seeded successfully
Initializing service [https]
Insecure file permissions on /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
Certificate: /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
Certificate loaded
Key file: /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
Private key loaded
SSL options set: 0x01000004
Configuration successful
Service [https] (FD=12) bound to 127.0.0.1:10051
Cannot open log file: /var/log/stunnel/stunnel.log
Closing service [https]
Service [https] closed (FD=12)
Sessions cached before flush: 0
Sessions cached after flush: 0
Service [https] closed
str_stats: 16 block(s), 1147 data byte(s), 928 control byte(s)
```

I assume this is some sort of rights issue, due to the 'chroot command' but I tried setting the rights on the stunnel log directory to 'nobody:nobody', that did not work. So I am not properly understanding what is happening. If I leave the 'chroot' and 'pid' line out it works? I am sure this is something obvious that I just don't see, any ideas?

I am running this on Centos 7

Comment: What does `strace` show going on for file (and the chroot) related calls? E.g. is it looking for `/var/run/stunnel/var/log/stunnel/stunnel.log` or... ?

Comment: Not sure but here is what I see with strace... chroot("/var/run/stunnel")              = 0
chdir("/")                              = 0
setgid(99)                              = 0
setgroups(1, [99])                      = 0
setuid(99)                              = 0
open("/var/log/stunnel/stunnel.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC, 0640) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)    Odd thing is the directory does exist and is owned by root...

Comment: It looks like it is looking for a directory owned by 'nobody:nobody' but I tried that and it did not work, if I am interpreting strace right?

Comment: @CharlesBunn Are you looking at `/var/log/stunnel` _within_ the chroot directory (you should).

Comment: I changed the log file so it would be in the same directory as the pid file and that worked but why! Now I am confused as to the reach of 'chroot'. Both the cert and key files work without being referenced to the chroot directory. Why do they work and log does not???

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **thrig** and **Kusalananda** I found a way to make this work by putting the log file in the `/var/run/stunnel` directory. Then after a reboot I recreate the directory with `sudo mkdir /var/run/stunnel` and then set the rights with `sudo chown nobody:nobody /var/run/stunnel` Although this disappears after a reboot at least while it is running I can see the log in the background during testing and after startup. I still do not understand why `chroot` does not affect the key and cert locations the same way it caused an issue with the log files?

Comment: Congratulations on getting to the bottom of this problem. Feel free to open a new/separate question for the remaining issue(s).

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the issue by using a relative path for the log file, like:

output = stunnel.log
chroot = /var/run/stunnel

Comment: I get an error when trying that - 'Log file must include full path name'

Comment: output = /stunnel.log   works - linux.